# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onAuthStateChanged') in Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I was  following a recent firebase authentication tutorial on YT and after running my code I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onAuthStateChanged')

and this is the piece of code thats throwing error:

```
import { useContext,createContext,useEffect,useState } from "react";
import { signInWithPopup,signOut,onAuthStateChanged,GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "firebase/auth"; 

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider =({children})=>{

const[user, setUser] = useState('client');

const googleSignIn =()=>{
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth,provider);
};

const logOut =()=>{
    signOut(auth);
};

useEffect(()=>{
    const Unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth,(currentUser)=>{
        setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return ()=>{
        Unsubscribe();
    }
},[user]);

return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user,logOut,googleSignIn}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const userAuth = ()=>{
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

when i looked up on the internet it showed that maybe my getAuth might not have been imported properly but i did import it in the following manner:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API-KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```